# Trigger event/external request when woocommerce plugin is installed/uninstalled?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How do I detect a new install or uninstall of a woocommerce plugin?
I haven't find any reference in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are two actions triggered upon plugins activation and deactivation. These are two the actions `activated_plugin` and `deactivated_plugin`

You may use them like this

```
function detect_plugin_activation(  $plugin, $network_activation ) {
    if( $plugin == "woocommerce/woocommerce.php" ) {
        // Woocommerce activated
        // Do your stuff here
    }   
}
add_action( 'activated_plugin', 'detect_plugin_activation', 10, 2 );

function detect_plugin_deactivation(  $plugin, $network_activation ) {
    if( $plugin == "woocommerce/woocommerce.php" ) {
        // Woocommerce deactivated
        // Do your stuff here
    }   
}
add_action( 'deactivated_plugin', 'detect_plugin_deactivation', 10, 2 );
```

There is one more action triggered by woocommerce itself at the time activation

```
function on_woocommerce_installed() {
    // This action triggered exclusivly by woocommerce at the time of activation
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_installed', 'on_woocommerce_installed' );
```